# How can I save java all lines from java console output to a text file and properly append it?

Tags: java, console, text-files, output

I am new to Java and have been trying to string some open source code together to search tweets and finally was able to succeed. Then I wanted to save the output to a text file. I searched and reviewed console out methods, filewriter, printwriter and I found one on here that works but it's saving only one tweet and overwrites the previous one it saves. How can I properly append the existing text file without overwriting a previous save and make sure it saves all the tweets from the console screen? Example code below:

```
    JSONObject js = new JSONObject(buff.toString());  
    JSONArray tweets = js.getJSONArray("results");  
    JSONObject tweet;  
    for(int i=0;i<tweets.length();i++) {  
        tweet = tweets.getJSONObject(i); 
        PrintWriter out;
         try {
        out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\tweet\\outputfile.txt"));
        System.out.println((i+1)+")http://twitter.com/"+tweet.getString("from_user")+" at "+tweet.getString("created_at"));  
        System.out.println(tweets.getJSONObject(i).getString("text")+"\n");
        out.println((i+1)+")http://twitter.com/"+tweet.getString("from_user")+" at "+tweet.getString("created_at"));
        out.println(tweets.getJSONObject(i).getString("text")+"\n");

         out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 


}
```

}
}

Comment: You have to append the output.

Comment: Do you wan't to append entire contend from console to file? In that case [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16238195/1393766) may interest you. This way you will have to print only to console without duplicating code to also write it to file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are so tantalizingly close.  You just need to open the `FileWriter` with append set to `true`.  Append will make it add to the end of the file, as opposed to overwriting it every time.

```
out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\tweet\\outputfile.txt", true));
```

Comment: thanks so much and for the fast replies! it's working the way it should be now

Comment: Your answer is amazing. Thanks for that! How Do i save each new message in a new line?

Comment: It depends on your code, but most likely you would just initialize the PrintWriter outside of the for loop. Then use out.println(); to potentially print a newline between tweets.

Answer (score 1):

Change this line (Because it will erase your previously written data):

```
out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\tweet\\outputfile.txt"));
```

For (Here you are setting Append mode to true)

```
out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\tweet\\outputfile.txt"), true);
```

Default mode is set to false so it will overwrite your file.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating object of `PrintWriter` and `FileWriter` object during each iteration of your `for loop` you should initialize  PrintWriter outside of you `for loop`(its will improve performance)finally to release resource.

```
PrintWriter  out = null ;
try
{
  // putting
  out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\tweet\\outputfile.txt"),true); // appending file if exists.
  // JSON Parsing instructions
  for(int i=0;i<tweets.length();i++) 
  { 
    // processing logic and write operation to file
  }
}
catch(CustomExceptions e) {//All other exception handling}
catch(Exception e){//Generic exception handling }
finally{
          if(out != null
          {
              out.close();
          }
       }
```

Answer (score -1):

public final String path ="your path"

```
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(path),true);/*automatically append the line you want to save and if false it will overwrite the data */
```

pw.write("what ever you want")

```
        pw.close();
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question posted.