# how to get a console output (e.g. on eclipse) AND write/copy the same output to file?

Tags: java, file-io, system, nio, printstream

I know that this type of question have been asked many times. But I didn't find any answer for myself. That's why i am asking once more.

I have got an output on my console. I want to copy the same output 1-to-1 to a file. I don't want to redirect. I want some kind of "copy" it and "write" into a file. 
I hope the question is clear enough, cause I have seen that the other times, the question wasn't clear.

Anyways, I have tried it with the "System.setOut" methode. But it just redirect everything to the file. 
I cannot write all the "System.out.println"s with a write() into a file, that to much.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Don't use a system out , rather just write to a file .. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15758685/how-to-write-logs-in-text-file-when-using-java-util-logging-logger

Comment: This may serve your needs
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16237546/writing-to-console-and-text-file

Comment: Thanx!
@Kenneth: I had alread found that. But the problem here was, it just went through my while and for loops and wrote and in the file the last output. I guess it overwrote just the others

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can get console output. You have to do everything before printing

To Write our to a file do this.

```
try{

FileWriter x = new FileWriter(new File("x.txt"));
x.write("hello");

}catch(IOExecption e){

}
```

That will write out hello to a file

Comment: but how can I do it? 
i got this one:
   FileOutputStream myFile = new 
                               FileOutputStream(task.getResultFile());
    PrintStream output = new PrintStream(in);

then everytime i called System.out.println(), I also called output.println(). But the problem was as i said to Kenneth, that it overwrite all the other lines and print in the file, only the last phrase, since i am using while and for loops.

Comment: You will need to call the `flush()` method on the FileWriter which writes the content of the buffer to the destination file.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this , the system out will happen after the log to file. 
This code will append. Please This is NOT a good example of Exception handling, just an example of what you can do.

```
  protected void writeToFileAndLog(String logEntry)
  {
    String file = "MyAmazingLog.txt";
    try
    {

      FileOutputStream appendedFile = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
      DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(appendedFile);

      out.writeBytes(String.format("%s\n", logEntry));
      out.flush();
      out.close();
      System.out.println(logEntry);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```