# Printing to System and to PrintWriter

Tags: java, printwriter, system.out

I have just over 100 lines of data and statistics that I need to print. I'm using:

```
PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter(fileName);
```

The reason why it's about 100 lines is because I need to print to both the System and the file (about 50 lines each). Is there any shorter way to print and "prettify" up my code?

```
System.out.println("Prints Stats"); //To System
p.println("Prints Stats"); //To File
etc
```

For every line printed to the System, there is an exact same line that is printed to the file. Is there a way to combine the two or to make it shorter? Or am I just stuck with this "ugly", long pile of prints?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Writing to console and text file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16237546/writing-to-console-and-text-file)

Comment: You could use a [Logger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html)...

Comment: Everything works fine Pshemo, I just want to find a way to concise it.

Comment: I know. Accepted answer shows one of ways to set up your code so you could just use `System.out.println` and have it printed in console and in file (so you wouldn't need additional lines which would invoke `p.println`).

Comment: Okay, thank you, I got that working. Now, is there a way to only print to the console now that I have done this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.

**Using a StringBuilder**

If you are not writing tons of text, you could use a `StringBuilder` to create your output by appending to it, inserting stuff inside it etc., and once it's ready, print it to both `p` and `System.out`.

```
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
b.append("Name: ").append("Susan").append("\n");
// Append more stuff to b, also insert and delete from it if you want.
System.out.print(b);
p.print(b);
```

**Writing your own `println()`**

If you're using just the `println()` method, you could write your own method that calls it for both writers:

```
private void println( String s ) {
    System.out.println(s);
    p.out.println(s);
}
```

That is, assuming `p` is a field and not a local variable.

**Using format**

Instead of using `println()` you could use the `printf()` or `format()` methods. The first parameter is a formatting string, and you can format several lines within one print using a format string. For example:

```
System.out.printf( "Name: %s%nSurname: %s%nAge: %d%n", "Susan", "Carter", 30 );
```

Would print

```
Name: Susan
Surname: Carter
Age: 30
```

And by using the same format string you can use two `printf`s to save on many `println`s:

```
String formatString = "Name: %s%nSurname: %s%nAge: %d%n";
Object[] arguments = { "Susan", "Carter", 30 );

p.printf( formatString, arguments );
System.out.printf( formatString, arguments );
```

This would print the above three-line output to your file and then to your System output.

Comment: Thanks, I wrote my own print method (called it printlnf) that way it can clear up a lot of code in my most convenient way, and it also accommodates for my need of also using console output that doesn't get directed to the file. Thanks!