# saving console without changing System.out.println("blabla");

Tags: java, log4j

I am very new at programming so my apologies in advance if my question is a bit primary.

I have a piece of JAVA code (more than 10,000 lines) and it has hundreds of `System.out.println("blabla");` and I need to save them in a .txt file. I cannot go through all of them and change the code so I was wondering if there is any way that I can add some lins of codes then run the program and finally save the logs when that Java program is finished.

Comment: Why can't you "go through all of them...?" You're not coding with pen and paper. Presumably you're using at least a text editor with find and replace functionality. Write yourself a little logging class that writes strings to a file, and wherever you're currently using System.out.println to dump log messages, call a method on your logging class instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this instruction somewhere at the beginning of your app:

```
System.setOut(new PrintStream("a.txt"));
```

UPDATE:
If you want to write both console and file you can implement simple SplitStream:

```
public class SplitStream extends OutputStream {
    OutputStream o1,o2;
    public SplitStream(OutputStream o1, OutputStream o2) {
        this.o1=o1; this.o2=o2;
    }
    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        o1.write(b);
        o2.write(b);
    }
}
```

then use it this way (in main):

```
OutputStream other=new FileOutputStream("a.txt");
System.setOut(new PrintStream(new SplitStream(System.out,other)));
```

Comment: worked like a charm :)

Comment: The only issue is that it stopped showing the logs in my IDE (Eclipse) console :(

Comment: Yes, you can implement some condition depending how you run.
Simplest is to add argument in eclipse run configuration.

Comment: could you explain a bit more, much appreciated

Comment: In Eclipse -> Run Configurations -> [you run config] -> Arguments add argument "logOnConsole", then in your main add condition:
`if (args.length==0 || !args[0].equals("logOnConsole")) System.setOut(new PrintStream("a.txt"));`
If your app needs command line arguments then you need add a little more logic to process all arguments

Answer (score 1):

Change the "out" from System.out to print to an output file.

```
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("output.txt"));
System.setOut(out);
```

Comment: The only issue is that it stopped showing the logs in my IDE (Eclipse) console :(

Comment: I thought you didn't care for it to be in the console anymore. Whilst it may be inefficient: At the end of the code, read the output.txt file and print its contents to the console.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not exactly the answer to your question, but a solution without changing any line of code is to invoke the program and redirect the output to the text file

```
java your.Program > logfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I want to write the data in both streams I try use [TeeOutputStream](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/output/TeeOutputStream.html) from [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/download_io.cgi). Add the code at the start of you program.

```
try {
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("BlaBla.txt"));
    //we will want to print in standard "System.out" and in "file"
    TeeOutputStream myOut=new TeeOutputStream(System.out, fos);
    PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(myOut);
    System.setOut(ps);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Thanks to [Writing to console and text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16237546/writing-to-console-and-text-file)