# How to print to a file and the monitor at the same time?

Tags: java, file, console, filewriter, printwriter

I am trying to print to a file while printing to the monitor at the same time. By the way, it prints to the monitor perfectly fine. My code doesn't even create the file. That is very confusing because I created a file in other parts of my code and it worked fine.

I am aware that there is a  [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16237546/writing-to-console-and-text-file) to a problem similar to mine however, I havent learned about FileOutputStream or PrintStream. I am in a intro to coding class and we can only use what was taught in class. Is there another way to accomplish this?

Below is my code.

```
public static void printLine(char n, int count) throws IOException //prints lines of chord
{


FileWriter file = new FileWriter("outFile.txt",true);
PrintWriter outputfile = new PrintWriter(file);
//File outFile = new File("outFile.txt");

char[] lineNames = {'f','d','B','G','E','C'};
char[] spaceNames = {'e','c','A','F','D'};

char[] lineAr = {'-','-',n,'-','-'}; //array to print lines
char[] spaceAr = {' ',' ',n,' ',' '}; //array to print spaces


//print line
if(n == lineNames[count])
{
  lineAr[2] = n;
}
else
  lineAr[2] = '-';
for(int x = 0; x<5; x++)
{
  System.out.print(lineAr[x]); //prints to monitor
  outputfile.print(lineAr[x]); //prints to output file
}//end for loop
System.out.println();

//print space
if(n == spaceNames[count])
{
  spaceAr[2] = n;
}
else
  spaceAr[2] = ' ';
for(int x = 0; x<5; x++)
{
  System.out.print(spaceAr[x]);
  outputfile.print(lineAr[x]);
}//end for loop
System.out.println();

//print line C
if(n == 'C')
{
  lineAr[2] = n;
}
else
  lineAr[2] = '-';
for(int x = 0; x<5; x++)
{
  System.out.print(lineAr[x]);
  outputfile.print(lineAr[x]);
}//end for loop
System.out.println();

 outputfile.close();  
 }//end printLine method
```

I tried manually making the file and had the code to print to that file however, the file is empty.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing to console and text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16237546/writing-to-console-and-text-file)

Comment: Thank you but I haven't learned about FileOutputStream and I can only use what we were taught in class. Is there another way to accomplish this? @vinS

Answer (score 1):

Try using `write()` instead of `print`

```
for(int x = 0; x<5; x++)
{
  System.out.print(lineAr[x]); //prints to monitor
  outputfile.write(lineAr[x]); //write to output file
}//end for loop
System.out.println();
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Unfortunately write doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

i hope this works

```
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("testfile.txt");
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        System.out.println("a");
        writer.append("a");
    }

    writer.close();
```

This will print to the console as well as write to the file - 'testfile.txt