# How can I redirect the System.out.println() of constructor of superclass to System.setOut() of subclass?

Tags: java

There are some multiple System.out.println() in the constructor of the superclass, and I have to redirect them to PrintStream object ps using System.setOut(ps).

for example, if I have a superclass like this:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class SuperClass implements ActionListener{

    public SuperClass(){
        System.out.println("Some message");
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "Some other message";
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        System.out.println(toString());
    }
}
```

and a subclass like this:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class SubClass extends SuperClass{

    private PrintStream ps;

    public SubClass(){
        super();

        try {
            ps = new PrintStream("file.txt");
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.getStackTrace();
        }

        System.setOut(ps);
    } 
}
```

whenever the action is performed (ex. pressing a JFrame Button from superclass), the System.out.println() from actionPerformed() is redirected to PrintStream object, but the System.out.println() from the constructor is not.

Also, how can I redirect the System.out to PrintStream object AND keep the System.out? (i.e. printing both System.out and PrintStream)

Comment: You would have to pass it into the super constructor.

Comment: Look like what you need is logging, take a look on https://logback.qos.ch/ to see how to set up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The problem is in constructors order.
   Shortly when you call `SubClass` constructor it calls `SuperClass` first, because you have to init parent first.( When you call subclass constructor,  it always call parent constructor first). This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23093470/java-order-of-initialization-and-instantiation) have answer about init order.
2. To add info for file and console adding logger can fit your aims. You can configure it in several ways. [Link](https://www.baeldung.com/java-logging-intro)
   If you want to write without logger, just to file and console, take a look for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16237546/writing-to-console-and-text-file)